# How is south african paprika different from Hungarian paprika?

Tags: spices, paprika

I am planning to make a spice blend, and the recipe I am using calls for south african paprika.  Stores near me only have Hungarian paprika.  How different are the flavors between these two varieties of paprika?

Answer (score 1):

The variety of the original pepper might be slightly different giving out different result when dried and ground up.

There might be a difference in spiciness.
There might be a difference in smokiness (if the paprika is smoked).

Hard to tell.

Just try it and report back.

Comment: If the OP doesn't already know the difference and can only find one kind to try, I doubt they're going to be able to report much about the differences or lack thereof.